# How to create QChart.js Line Chart

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm able to get [QChart.js](https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js) to work with pie charts without issues (as well as polar and doughnut charts), but whenever I try to create a line chart (as well as radar and bar charts) I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The working code for pie charts is as follows:

```
Chart {
    id: chart_line
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    chartType: Charts.ChartType.PIE

    chartData: [
        {value: 15, color: "#6AA84F"},
        {value:  3, color: "#DC3912"},
        {value:  5, color: "#FF9900"}]
}
```

The broken code for line charts is as follows:

```
Chart {
    id: chart_line
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    chartType: Charts.ChartType.LINE

    chartData: [
        {labels: ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
         datasets: [{ data: [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]} ] }
    ]
}
```

My understanding is that I'm not loading in `chartData` properly. The charts I'm having issues with are all the ones that use lists in their declarations in [QChartGallery.js](https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js/blob/master/QChartGallery.js). I'm not especially familiar with JavaScript and it seems something about my syntax is off and I can't find documentation to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, turns out it was about exactly as silly of a solution as I thought it might be. For these kinds of charts, you need to update the `chartData` on `Component.onCompleted`. So, the working example code for anyone in the future having this problem is as follows:

```
Chart {
    id: chart_line
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    chartType: Charts.ChartType.LINE

    Component.onCompleted: {
        chartData = {
            labels: ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets: [{
                    data: [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                }]
        }
    }
}
```